# Visualise map data in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, gis

I have postcode level data in an Excel workbook and ideally I would like to have a map on another sheet of the area that I am interested in. The postcodes in my dataset should be highlighted within that map. I am using Excel 2010 and have no prior experience with GIS but plenty of experience with C#, Java. Any ideas of how I can achieve this? I looked for open source add-ins and didn't find an awful lot. Is there another way I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Topo.ly](http://topo.ly). You can just copy all your post codes from Excel and paste them in Topo.ly, and it will plot them on Google Maps. It also hosts your maps, so you can save it and come back to it later, or share it with others.

Comment: http://topo.ly is now known as https://mapline.com Disclaimer: I work for mapline.com

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to that solution for non-gis-users: 
http://www.esri.com/software/esri-maps-for-office

It requires Office 2010 (that's no problem in your case) and it is based on a **privative** GIS software (no FLOSS). On the videos section there are some examples.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a good starting point. You will need some knowledge of WPF

[Bing Maps Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Control, Version 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165)

Then using VSTO you can integrate it into Excel
[Using WPF Controls in Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772076.aspx)

Sample WPF application is @ [Integrating Bing Maps With WPF](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/04/01/Map-Your-Apps.aspx?Page=1)

**Edit** :

Didnt find much on non WPF solution but you can give this a try

[Integrating Virtual Earth Maps and Excel 2007 Using Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc531008.aspx)

Download here http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VSTOVirtualEarthXL

Comment: Thanks I will have a look on that. I would prefer if I didn't have to use WPF however.

Comment: I see that's quite a clever way of doing it actually. Thanks Amitd!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference or someone who has similar porblem, you can use an Excel add-in called Funfun to create data map in Excel 2016. I made two examples here.

[image]

[image]

As you could see, there is some code in the middle section of the screenshot. That is because Funfun allows you to write and run JavaScript code directly in Excel, also, the JavaScript code could use the data stored in the sheet. The capability of using JavaScript means that you could use 3rd party libraries like HighCharts.js or D3.js to plot charts like data map. In those two examples, I actually used highmaps which is part of the HighCharts.js library. The highmaps.js already has different templates from world map to specific map of different countries. I believe you could find the map you need.

Funfun also has an online editor in which you could test your JavaScript code with you data. You could check the detailed code of the examples above on the link below.

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a5c9a50404f66229bda3ae0

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5925036104ce702ccfb22b0e

If you are satisfied with the result you achieved in the online editor, you could easily load the result into you Excel using the URL above. Of couse first you need to insert the Funfun add-in from **Insert - My add-ins**. Here are some screenshots showing how you could do this.

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***